# Affect on existing features in the app when Bitcode enabled vs disabled

Tags: ios, swift, clang, bitcode

Does enabling or disabling bitcode would affect the existing features of the app in any way ?

For eg: If I choose to untick the option "Rebuild from bitcode" while sharing the ipa to QA team and on the other hand If I chose to enable bitcode when I am uploading the app to AppStore.

Is there any possibility that the some test cases might go live untested ?

[image]

[image]